# How to parse coordinates from a text file in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, coordinates

I have a text file named coordinates.txt with some coordinates in it(surprisingly). The format looks like this:

```
20.580070,47.775910, 
20.582950,47.776640, 
20.585660,47.777460, 
20.587280,47.777960, 
20.588280,47.778300, 
20.621870,47.789710,
```

I want to parse through the file, and add the first coordinate to an int variable named latitude and the second one to an int variable named longitude. Than print out the two variables to the console and do this for every line separately.I know I should use a loop but I am not exactly sure how so can you guys please help me out!

**EDIT:**

Here is my code so far:

```
        NSString *latitude = @"0";
        NSString *longitude = @"0";
        NSString* filePath = @"/Users/Balazs/coordinates.txt";



        NSString *entireFileInString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        NSArray *lines = [entireFileInString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        for (NSString *line in lines) {
                latitude = line;
        }
        NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",latitude]);
```

I know how to read the whole text into the latitude variable but not just the first part and not line by line. Also the text which is read is stored as a string so I am not sure how to convert those into doubles..

PS: Sorry for the noob question!!:/

Comment: Why would you store such decimal values in an `int` variable? Use `double`. How many lines are in the file (roughly)? Dozens or thousands?

Comment: Yeah thats my first mistake..I will change them to doubles! There won't be more lines than 400

Comment: What research have you done so far to look into reading the file and splitting the strings? This is a common task. Some searching will reveal all kinds of options.

Comment: I have an answer ready and waiting for you @BalázsVincze, but yeah, like rmaddy said, it would be good to know what you've tried so far.

Comment: Yeah sorry guys for not making everything clear.. I attached the code I have done so far into the original post!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the text file's in your bundle, you can store the text in an `NSString` like so:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"coordinates" 
                                                 ofType:@"txt"];

NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                 error:NULL];
```

Then separate the text into lines using `componentsSeparatedByString:`, go through each line with a loop, then separate each line again using `componentsSeparatedByString:` into its longitude and latitude values before printing. For example:

```
NSArray *lines = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *line in lines) {
    NSArray *values = [line componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    double latitude = [[values objectAtIndex:0] doubleValue];
    double longitude = [[values objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
    NSLog(@"%f, %f", latitude, longitude);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LyndseyScott! This just saved my project!! :))

Comment: @BalázsVincze No problem :) And thanks for sharing your original code... it makes us feel better if we don't feel as if we're doing all your work for you. ;) You were on the right track with your code, but made several mistakes, ex. not taking the carriage return into account, not printing within the loop, etc. so hopefully looking at my answer will help you understand those concepts a little bit better.

Comment: Do have to release the text files from the memory after they are done being read? If yes, how? Thanks!

Comment: @BalázsVincze If it's in your bundle you can't delete it from memory. And even if it's not in your bundle, you don't *have* to delete anything. Unless you're not using ARC, "releasing" things from memory doesn't really apply.